# Convert text within string to numeric

Tags: r, string, text, dplyr

I'm struggling to create a new variable off a text string.  Here is a sample of my data frame:

```
  Brand     Pack_Content
1 Dove      4X25 G
2 Snickers  250 G
3 Twix      2X20.7 G
4 Korkunov  BULK
```

I would like to create a numeric variable called Grams.  I've tried solutions using gsub or separate, but the need to for different solutions by row (i.e., some need to multiply the Brand Packs with multiple packs (i.e., 4X25 G)) has me stumped.  A solution with dplyr is preferred.

```
  Brand     Pack_Content    Grams
1 Dove      4X25 G          100
2 Snickers  250 G           250
3 Twix      2X20.7 G        41.4
4 Korkunov  BULK            1000
```

Comment: I don't think there is a magic bullet for you solution. I would look at building a function that has a combination of `if` statements, `gsub` and `strsplit`, then `sapply` on the `Pack_Content` table variable. You will need to handle conditions for "BULK" and listings that split on "X". This assumes that the example you gave contains all versions of the elements found in `Pack_Content`.

Comment: you could use a regular expression like this one to pull out the numbers, and then use the previous comment to build up a function that does what you need: `^\s*([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)(?:\s*[xX]\s*([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+))?(?:\s*G)?\s*$`  As always, test our your regular expressions at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) with some test data to make sure your regex works as expected.   Also, you'll need to escape the slashes in the R string literal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr). The key is before using `separate` to separate the `Pack_Content_new` column, replace all the strings, such as "G" or "BULK" with "" or meaningful numbers. If you have more than one meaningful strings like "BULK", you may want to use `case_when` in addition to `recode`. Arfter the `separate` function, we can replace `NA` with 1 in the `Number` column. Finnaly, we can calculate the `Grams` based on numbers in `Number` and `Unit_Weight`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(Pack_Content_new = sub("G$", "", Pack_Content)) %>%       # Remove the last G
  mutate(Pack_Content_new = recode(Pack_Content_new,               # Replace BULK with 1000
                                   `BULK` = "1000")) %>% 
  separate(Pack_Content_new, into = c("Number", "Unit_Weight"),    # Separate the Pack_Content_new column
           sep = "X", convert = TRUE, 
           fill = "left") %>%
  replace_na(list(Number = 1)) %>%                                 # Replace NA in Number with 1
  mutate(Grams = Number * Unit_Weight)                             # Calculate the Grams
dat2
#      Brand Pack_Content Number Unit_Weight  Grams
# 1     Dove       4X25 G      4        25.0  100.0
# 2 Snickers        250 G      1       250.0  250.0
# 3     Twix     2X20.7 G      2        20.7   41.4
# 4 Korkunov         BULK      1      1000.0 1000.0
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "  Brand     Pack_Content
1 Dove      '4X25 G'
                  2 Snickers  '250 G'
                  3 Twix      '2X20.7 G'
                  4 Korkunov  'BULK'",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

*Update: added in some unit extraction and conversions just for the heck of it*

*Update 2: Threw in some validation steps (for my own reference if no-one else) that should probably have been part of the original answer. In general, if you're using regular expressions to extract values (and you don't have time to review every single row of output in detail), it's easy to get burned when some corner case input format that wasn't considered comes along*

Using `data.table`,`stringi`, and the sweet, sweet, magic of regular expressions:

#### A note on tool selection here:

Since regular expressions are difficult to follow enough on their own, I think it's a safer bet to focus on making the transformation steps readable and clearly defined instead of trying to cram it all into a series of pipes and as few lines of code possible.

Since `dplyr` doesn't allow for step by step manipulation (no pipes) without re-assigning the tibble after each expression, I feel `data.table` is far more elegant and efficient tool for this kind of data munging work.

#### Create Data

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

DT <- data.table(Brand = c("Dove","Snickers","Twix","Korkunov","Reeses","M&M's"),
                 Pack = c("4X25 G","0.250 KG","2X20.7 G","BULK","2.5.5X4G","2 X 3 X 3G"))
```

#### Pre Cleaning

First off we'll strip out spaces and make everything uppercase

```
## Strip out Spaces
DT[,Pack := gsub("[[:space:]]+","",Pack)]
## Make everything Uppercase
DT[,Pack := toupper(Pack)]
```

#### Assumption Validation

Before we use regular expressions to extract values and do some math on them, it's probably prudent to do some validation steps to make sure we don't get burned down the road by an unexpected corner case.

```
## Start off by trusting nothing
DT[,Valid := FALSE]
## Mark Packs that fit formats like "BULK" as valid
DT[Pack %in% c("BULK"),Valid := TRUE]
## Mark Packs that fit formats like "4X20G" or "3.0X3KG" as valid
DT[stri_detect_regex(Pack,"^([[:digit:]]+\\.){0,1}[[:digit:]]+X([[:digit:]]+\\.){0,1}[[:digit:]]+(G|KG)$"),
   Valid := TRUE]
## Mark Packs that fit formats like "250G" as valid
DT[stri_detect_regex(Pack,"^([[:digit:]]+\\.){0,1}[[:digit:]]+(G|KG)$"),
   Valid := TRUE]

print(DT)
```

At this point:

```
      Brand     Pack Valid
1:     Dove    4X25G  TRUE
2: Snickers  0.250KG  TRUE
3:     Twix  2X20.7G  TRUE
4: Korkunov     BULK  TRUE
5:   Reeses 2.5.5X4G FALSE
6:    M&M's   2X3X3G FALSE
```

#### Extracting Values

*Note that we are only populating values for rows that met pre-defined expectations for what a valid format is.*

```
## Extract the first number at the beginning of the "Pack" column followed by an X
DT[Valid == TRUE, Quantity := as.numeric(stri_extract_first_regex(Pack,"^([[:digit:]]+\\.){0,1}[[:digit:]]+(?=X)"))]
## Extract last number out of the "Pack" column
DT[Valid == TRUE, Unit_Weight := as.numeric(stri_extract_last_regex(Pack,"([[:digit:]]+\\.){0,1}[[:digit:]]+"))]
## Extract the Units
DT[Valid == TRUE, Units := stri_extract_last_regex(Pack,"[[:alpha:]]+$")]

print(DT)
```

Now we've got the following:

```
      Brand     Pack Valid Quantity Unit_Weight Units
1:     Dove    4X25G  TRUE        4       25.00     G
2: Snickers  0.250KG  TRUE       NA        0.25    KG
3:     Twix  2X20.7G  TRUE        2       20.70     G
4: Korkunov     BULK  TRUE       NA          NA  BULK
5:   Reeses 2.5.5X4G FALSE       NA          NA    NA
6:    M&M's   2X3X3G FALSE       NA          NA    NA
```

### Convert units, fill in NA's, calculate weights

Now we just have to go back and fill in rows where there wasn't a weight or a quantity, optionally convert units, etc. so we can calculate weight.

```
## Start with a standard conversion factor of 1
DT[Valid == TRUE, Unit_Factor := 1]
## Make some Unit Conversions
DT[Units == "KG", Unit_Factor := 1000]
## Fill in Rows without a quantity with a value of 1
DT[Valid == TRUE & is.na(Quantity), Quantity := 1]
## Fill in a weight for Bulk units
DT[Pack == "BULK", `:=` (Unit_Weight = 1000, Units = "G")]
## And finally, calculate Weight in grams
DT[Valid == TRUE, Grams := Unit_Weight*Quantity*Unit_Factor]

print(DT)
```

Which yields a final result:

```
      Brand     Pack Valid Quantity Unit_Weight Units Unit_Factor  Grams
1:     Dove    4X25G  TRUE        4       25.00     G           1  100.0
2: Snickers  0.250KG  TRUE        1        0.25    KG        1000  250.0
3:     Twix  2X20.7G  TRUE        2       20.70     G           1   41.4
4: Korkunov     BULK  TRUE        1     1000.00     G           1 1000.0
5:   Reeses 2.5.5X4G FALSE       NA          NA    NA          NA     NA
6:    M&M's   2X3X3G FALSE       NA          NA    NA          NA     NA
```

#### (All the steps, in condensed form)

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

DT <- data.table(Brand = c("Dove","Snickers","Twix","Korkunov","Reeses","M&M's"),
                 Pack = c("4X25 G","0.250 KG","2X20.7 G","BULK","2.5.5X4G","2 X 3 X 3G"))

DT[,Pack := gsub("[[:space:]]+","",Pack)]
DT[,Pack := toupper(Pack)]
DT[,Valid := FALSE]
DT[Pack %in% c("BULK"),Valid := TRUE]
DT[stri_detect_regex(Pack,"^([[:digit:]]+\\.){0,1}[[:digit:]]+X([[:digit:]]+\\.){0,1}[[:digit:]]+(G|KG)$"), Valid := TRUE]
DT[stri_detect_regex(Pack,"^([[:digit:]]+\\.){0,1}[[:digit:]]+(G|KG)$"), Valid := TRUE]
DT[Valid == TRUE, Quantity := as.numeric(stri_extract_first_regex(Pack,"^([[:digit:]]+\\.){0,1}[[:digit:]]+(?=X)"))]
DT[Valid == TRUE, Unit_Weight := as.numeric(stri_extract_last_regex(Pack,"([[:digit:]]+\\.){0,1}[[:digit:]]+"))]
DT[Valid == TRUE, Units := stri_extract_last_regex(Pack,"[[:alpha:]]+$")]
DT[Valid == TRUE, Unit_Factor := 1]
DT[Units == "KG", Unit_Factor := 1000]
DT[Valid == TRUE & is.na(Quantity), Quantity := 1]
DT[Pack == "BULK", `:=` (Unit_Weight = 1000, Units = "G")]
DT[Valid == TRUE, Grams := Unit_Weight*Quantity*Unit_Factor]
```

#### A final note:

I'm assuming you didn't include all the messy, dirty details of how all over the place your raw data is, so you might need to add some more steps to capture cases where you have pounds instead of grams (and all those other corner cases).

Still, with 5-7 regular expressions I think you'd probably be able to cover at least a decent amount of your potential cases.

I keep [this Regex cheatsheet on RStudio's website](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf) within arms reach most of the time.

#### A relevant XKCD:

[image: Relevant XKCD]

Answer (score 1):

I know you need a plyr solution. Have you tried all the methods of Base R? Well here is just a small one. Hope this helps even though its not a plyr method.

First you need to remain with the numbers and also substitute `X` with `*`.  This is done by the use of `sub` function. We also replace the one that does not contain a number with 1000. Then we just evaluate the content obtained:

```
A=sub("X","*",sub("\\s.*","",dat$Pack_Content))
transform(dat,Grams=sapply(parse(text=replace(A,-grep("\\d",A),1000)),eval))
     Brand Pack_Content  Grams
1     Dove       4X25 G  100.0
2 Snickers        250 G  250.0
3     Twix     2X20.7 G   41.4
4 Korkunov         BULK 1000.0
```

Data Used:

```
dat=structure(list(Brand = c("Dove", "Snickers", "Twix", "Korkunov"
), Pack_Content = c("4X25 G", "250 G", "2X20.7 G", "BULK")), .Names = c("Brand", 
"Pack_Content"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4"))
```